# How do I configure SublimeLinter-contrib-rustc to find the "piston" crate?

Tags: rust, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I'm building a Rust game with Piston and I'm trying to use the [SublimeLinter Rust package](https://github.com/oschwald/SublimeLinter-contrib-rustc). When I open my .rs game files, I get this linter error:

```
extern crate piston; // linter error: "can't find crate for 'piston'"
```

If I check the Sublime console, I can see that the linter is finding rustc:

```
SublimeLinter: rust activated: /usr/local/bin/rustc
```

I don't see any obvious error messages in the console. I have piston listed as a dependency in my Cargo.toml and I'm able to `cargo run` successfully.

I'm a complete Rust & SublimeLinter newbie.

I get a similar error for whichever import I put first; for example if I move `extern crate graphics;` to be the first line in the file I get the error "can't find crate for 'graphics'".

**EDIT**: turns out enabling the "use-cargo" setting fixed the issue. I added a ".sublimelinterrc" file to my project root with these contents:

```
{
  "linters": {
    "rust": {
      "use-crate-root": true,
      "use-cargo": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I was having this issue too but enabling `use-cargo` fixed it for me. Have you tried setting the crate root and the use-crate-root settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not been able to reproduce your error. However, I'll list what I did that seemed to work. Perhaps you will see a step where we diverged, and that will give you a hint of where to look.

I installed Sublime Text 3. I chose the stable channel, build 3083. I [installed Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation), and then three packages:

1. SublimeLinter (3.5.1)
2. Sublime​Linter-contrib-rustc (1.3.5)
3. Rust (2015.05.28.16.43.21)

I restarted Sublime Text and opened a project of mine that uses Cargo and depends on other packages. I opened the console (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd>) and [enabled debug mode](http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/troubleshooting.html#debug-mode), which takes effect at the next Sublime restart.

Because I have non-standard install of Rust, I saw that Sublime was unable to run `rustc` due to missing dynamic libraries. I then closed Sublime, and opened it from my terminal: `open /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime\ Text`. This uses my environment variables set by my shell.

I saw that the linter was complaining that my library had no `main` method, so I [enabled the `use-cargo` option](https://github.com/oschwald/SublimeLinter-contrib-rustc#settings).

```
SublimeLinter: rust output:
error: main function not found
error: aborting due to previous error
```

After changing the `use-cargo` setting, I caused a deliberate syntax error in my code and saw that it was highlighted. I then misnamed the crate in the `extern crate` line, and saw it was highlighted.

At no point did there seem to be a problem with finding crates. I could tell that `cargo` was being used via the console:

```
SublimeLinter: rust output:
    Updating registry `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`
 Downloading rand v0.3.9
...
```

Comment: Thanks! Turns out I didn't enable "use-cargo" setting properly.